# Muticast - does total order imply causal order?

Tags: multicast, distributed-system

I''m learning about multicast in class but I'm struggling to see the difference between causal and total order. Assuming that there are no failures, does total order also mean that causal ordering is satisified?

Ive tried to come up with counterexamples but haven't been able to think of any.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding ordering is to use definitions of Total and Causal orders.

Total order means that we take any two events/message, then we can aways say which one came before the other. In total order, if A comes before B, it does not imply that B depends on A in any way. But if there are two events X&Y and Y depends on X (X happened before Y); then in (correct) total order X will come before Y.

Here is an example; let's say we own a bank. We have a banking system which transfers money from one account to another. Also, our system is single threaded and writes all events to a text file. And we have just two events: add (put) money to account and take money from an account.

To keep things simple, a money transfer is just two events: take and put. And we always will start with "take" to be on a safe side. So if Alice has 100$ and wants to transfer 10$ to Bob; then we will have two events:

- take 10$ from Alice's account
- put 10$ to Bob's account

Also, we will assume, both operations are manual, executed by humans. So two transfer may happen at the same time: Alice gives 10$ to Bob and Alex gives 15$ to Sam. e,g, two different tellers work with Alice and Alex in different branches of our bank.

With each transfer being two events, and humans executing those events, and having our system single threaded, we may end up with this log of events:

- take 10$ from Alice
- take 15$ from Alex
- put 15$ to Sam
- put 10$ to Bob

This is our total order. If we take any two events, we can see in the total order which one comes before the other.

At the same time, just because one event is before the other, it does not mean that those events are casually related; while one operator did took 10$ from Alice before another operator took 15$ from Alex - this does not mean that these events are related. We could have them in other sequence and that would be ok.

At the same time, take/put pairs are causally related; so every take myst came before corresponding put in the total order for the correctness.

Back to your question:

"Assuming that there are no failures, does total order also mean that causal ordering is satisfied?" - yes, as I said in the beginning, if Y depends on X, then X will come in the total order before the Y. All other events can come in any order.